# how to take sql backup without login

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help as I am unable to log into a database.

Some Error is coming like...

```
unable to start service MS SQL SERVER ON SERVER SERVER.(MSCORLIB)


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider: name pipes provider, error 40 could not open a connection to sql server) (Microsoft sql server, error :2)
```

My question is how can I take the backup now because I am unable to login into the sql.

Comment: So, you're trying to access data you specifically protected with login credentials without supplying any login credentials? With an enterprise level database like SQL Server? Good luck... you'll have to look into recovering the SA password, that's the first stop. No login = no luck.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. do i have any option...because i am not able to log in into the data base...

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server service is running? It seems like you have problems starting your SQL Server service.

Comment: yes, if i start the services in services.msc it is giving one error.i am unable to tell the error but some times it is showing started like that it is showing. I went to sql 2005 configuration manager then if is see the SQL SERVER IT IS IN RED COLOR IF I TRY TO RESTART THE The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details

Comment: Did you try to turn it off and turn it on again :) ?

Comment: which one should i trun it off..services.. or

Comment: I would check the event log for errors and eventually restart the whole computer.

Comment: Event id observed 9003

Comment: Seems you have corrupted master database, so restarting will not help.

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sql  2005 Any information

Comment: i have not corrupted client machine...

Comment: suppose if they forget to took the backup ... how to restore latest backup any options..

Answer (score 1):

As you have event in 9003 in your Event Log it indicates that you have corrupted `master` datatbase and you will need to rebuild it.

First check your disks for errors and fix them.

Then you will need to rebuild the master database:

For SQL Server 2005 check this:

http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting007.htm

or

http://thedbavault.blogspot.cz/2013/01/ms-sql-server-2005-rebuild-master.html

Also some recommend to use database file from another instance of the same version of SQL Server.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2011/02/01/the-easiest-way-to-rebuild-the-sql-server-master-database.aspx

Then you should be able to restore non-corrupted backup copy of your master database.

If you do not have backup of your master database, then you will have to recreate all logins, users, roles, permissions etc.

---

To backup data without running SQL Server you can only backup database files `.mdf`, `.ldf`.